# How to integrate http2 with ExpressJS using nodejs module http2?

Tags: node.js, express, http2

I am creating an api with nodejs and express and I want to integrate http2 with ExpressJS

This is my code:

```
'use strict';

const http2 = require('http2');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 443;

// Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Routes variables
const indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

// Routes uses
app.use('/', indexRouter);

// Server configurations
const key = path.join(__dirname + '/security/key.pem');
const cert = path.join(__dirname + '/security/certificate.pem');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(key),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(cert)
}

const server = http2.createSecureServer(options, app);

server.on('error', err => console.log(err));

server.listen(port, () => {
   console.log('Server running')
})
```

I am trying to pass express server as second parameter of createSecureServer() but I am not sure if I am right with this, cause I am getting this error:

> [nodemon] 2.0.2 [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs` [nodemon]
> watching dir(s): *.* [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
> [nodemon] starting `node index.js`
> _http_incoming.js:96   if (this.socket.readable)
> ^
>
> TypeError: **Cannot read property 'readable' of undefined**
> at IncomingMessage._read (_http_incoming.js:96:19)
> at IncomingMessage.Readable.read (*stream_readable.js:491:10)
> at resume* (_stream_readable.js:976:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) [nodemon] app crashed -
> waiting for file changes before starting...

It should be noted that my certificate, although self-signed and unreliable, is loading correctly.
I try not to use a third-party module if I can do it with NodeJS. Any help?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`expressjs` still does not officially support Node `http2`.

[image]

**[For more details visit here](https://expressjs.github.io/statusboard/)**

But you can use `node-spdy`. With this module, you can create HTTP2 / SPDY servers in node.js with natural http module interface and fallback to regular https (for browsers that support neither HTTP2 nor SPDY yet):

```js
const spdy = require('spdy')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const port = 3000
const app = express()

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res
    .status(200)
    .json({message: 'ok'})
})
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server.key'),
  cert:  fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/server.crt')
}
console.log(options)
spdy
  .createServer(options, app)
  .listen(port, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(error)
      return process.exit(1)
    } else {
      console.log('Listening on port: ' + port + '.')
    }
  })
```

For more datils on `spdy`, [visit here](https://github.com/spdy-http2/node-spdy).

If you have an option for other frameworks you can use **'KOA'** or **'HAPI'** which have support for node `http2`. [This might be useful for you](https://ivanjov.com/running-express-koa-and-hapi-on-http-2/)

Also, Read this [Release 5.0#2237](https://github.com/expressjs/express/pull/2237). It says that:

> The goal of Express 5 is to be API tweaks & the removal of all code
> from the Express repository, moving into components in the pillarjs
> project (https://github.com/pillarjs), providing at least basic
> support for promise-returning handlers and complete HTTP/2
> functionality. Express 5 would become a "view into pillarjs" and would
> be an arrangement of these components.

Comment: At today day, do you recommend me to use Nginx Proxy to bypass Express and use HTTP/2? I am using micro service architecture with Kubernetes.

Comment: 2 years on. Is this resolved at `Express` side? Or still have to use `spdy`?

Comment: It looks like express 5.0 is still in beta: https://expressjs.com/

Comment: This is still not implemented. I believe it is waiting on this PR at the moment:
https://github.com/expressjs/compression/pull/170
I'm looking at moving to fastify

Comment: I posted in the express js gitter channel about getting that pr merged, but it seems very dead. I think it is time to move to fastify

Answer (score 0):

I have found two solutions how to run HTTP2 server with Express.js.

Solution 1 (source: https://dirask.com/snippets/Express-js-run-server-using-HTTP2-h2-or-h2c-p5ddRD):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const spdy = require('spdy');        // npm install spdy
const express = require('express');  // npm install express

const credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'key.pem'), 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert.pem'), 'utf8'),
};

const app = express();

// ...

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Hello World!');
});

// ...

const server = spdy.createServer(credentials, app);

server.listen(8443, () => console.log('Server started on https://localhost:8443'));
```

Solution 2 (source: https://dirask.com/snippets/Express-js-run-server-using-HTTP2-h2-or-h2c-1b88wp):

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const http2 = require('http2');
const express = require('express');              // npm install express
const bridge = require('http2-express-bridge');  // npm install http2-express-bridge

const credentials = {
    key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'key.pem'), 'utf8'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'cert.pem'), 'utf8'),
};

const app = bridge(express);

// ...

app.get('/', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Hello World!');
});

// ...

const server = http2.createSecureServer(credentials, app);

server.listen(8443, () => console.log('Server started on https://localhost:8443'));
```